# Passing variables between view controllers

Tags: ios, properties, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am using this function to switch between views in Xcode 4.3.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextView" sender:self];
```

I would like to pass some parameters between pages. How can I do that?

Comment: did u tried using Navigation Controller instead. it is really simple to pass values

Comment: no, I didn't try Navigation Controller. I use regular button and segue in the storyboard.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` your view controler will call

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

assuming your new view controller has some propertys to set:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NextView"]) {
    MyViewController *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    myVC.propertyToSet = // set your properties here
}
```

Comment: so, I set the property like you said, and how can I read value from that property. And also, what if I need to pass multiple variables to the next view?

Comment: For multiple variables use multiple properties and to read from a property use ... = self.property (in your view controller where you defined that property)

Comment: I understand that, but I am not sure how to get that data in the "NextView".

Comment: Along the lines of Pfitz's approach, I create a method in my destination view controller to handle any initialization or customization.  For example, in Pfitz's example, substitute myVC.propertyToSet with `[myVC setProperty1:self.property1 viewTitle:@"My Title" delegate:self];`

Comment: Okay, I got that. I am just confused how can I access that variable in the NextView. Should I define a property with the same name and it will be automatically set?

Comment: In NextView use self.property e.g self.title

Answer (score 5):

This question has a very nice and correct explanation of passing data between view controllers:

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/870155)

Comment: yes it is nice explained on that page, but they are using pushViewController for view change, but I would like to use performSegueWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer from Pfitz, but I made it a little easier to understand for folks who are new to Objective-C using an example:

1. In your destinationViewController.h file add property setting for variable to 'receive' value from  your source controller.m file

   ```
   @property (nonatomic) int billIdReceivingVote;
   ```
2. Import your destinationViewController.h to your sourceViewController.m file:

   ```
   // VOLViewController.m
   #import "VOLVoteViewController.h
   ```
3. Add `prepareForSegue` method to your sourceViewController.m file and pass the variables

   ```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
       VOLVoteViewController *myDestinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

       // myDestinationViewController.variable = sourceViewController variabe
       myDestinationViewController.billIdReceivingVote = [self.idOfBillSelected intValue];
   }
   ```