# Detect which button was pressed to open this view

Tags: ios, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing variables between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577484/passing-variables-between-view-controllers)

Let's say I have 3 buttons in the same `ViewController(FirstController)` with tags from 1-3. All three buttons opened a new `ViewController(SecondController)`. But how can I, in the `SecondController`, check what button was pressed to get here, or maybe what segue was used? So the `SecondController` can perform different depending on which button was pressed to open it. I was maybe thinking about a switch and case.

Comment: What about storing clicked buttn tag in a shared variable or using a notification?

Comment: I answered your similar question earlier today, and showed you how to do this. Did you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible ways of doing this.

One way is to assign a unique segue to each button. On the method `prepareForSegue:` you identify the button and give that information to the `destinationViewController`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Button1Segue"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setButton:1];
    }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Button2Segue"]) {
    ...
}
```

---

The other way would be to create a `property` where you store the last pressed button.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTap:(id)sender {

    self.lastPressedButton = sender.tag;
}
```

and in `prepareForSegue:` you would do:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondControllerSegue"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setButton: self.lastPressedButton];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
if (button.tag == 0) {
   NSLog(@"Button one.");
} else if (button.tag == 1) {
   NSLog(@"Button two.");
}
```

You would put something like this in the method that occurs just before the action of your three buttons. That could be viewWillDisappear, prepareForSegue, etc.

Best of luck!