# How to make textFields from different classes equal the same text?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm Beginner in iOS development. In my `FirstViewController` I have two textFields and I use the `UITextFieldDelegate` to make these two equal the same content. In my `SecondViewController` I have another textField and I need to make it have the same content with the textFields from the `FirstViewController`.

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _FirstTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    SecondTextField.text = textField.text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple
pass the text of text field in FirstViewController to SecondViewController
using string and assign the passed string to the text field of SecondViewController

For passing the string you can have many option

1) Using Segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"secondViewSegue"]) {
    SecondViewController *objVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    objVC.strText = textfeld.text;
}
```

2) Passing data directly while pushing

```
SecondViewController *objVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
objVC.strText = textfield.text;
[self pushViewController:objVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable to the second View Controller in the Segue.

[Passing variables between view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577484/passing-variables-between-view-controllers)